# What is causing calls to sharepoint server vti_bin\sites.asmx

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0

We are looking at logs on our sharepoint and see a call to this web service from several PC's.

The calls apprear very regular every 5 mins, when the PC is on.

Anyone know what is causing this?

**Edit**

The agent in the iis log is: Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+HO32602;+HO32600;+HO32501;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727)

Comment: If you run a tool like Fiddler on one of those clients, it will tell you the name of the process that is making the calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe:

- Office
- Workspace/Groove sync
- Some custom client application
- SharePoint Designer
- Browser

Whats the user agent reported in the logs?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above (which is likely) it could be one of the desktop search products that MS has created.